# Using RSKImageCropper library in Swift Project

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios-library

Im trying to use [RSKImageCropper](https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKImageCropper) in my Swift project but dont know how.
I have an Bridging-header file with this line of code

```
#import "RSKImageCropViewController.h"
```

In my Controller i can create an instance of RSKImageCropViewController like this

```
let imageCropVC = RSKImageCropViewController()
```

but after that, i cant get it to work. When calling `imageCropVC.initWithImage()` i get an error.
Im trying to convert the example Objectiv-C methode on the github page to Swift.

What am i doing wrong? Is it even possible to use this library in my Swift project? 
It would be nice if someone could post the right code in Swift.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing it's because `imageCropVC` is already an initialized object. Looking at the header file, I think you may try using `let imageCropVC = RSKImageCropViewController(initWithImage: ...)` instead? Just a thought.

Comment: i got it to work. Your answer was kind of correct.
this is how it looks now `let imageCropVC = RSKImageCropViewController(image: image)`

Comment: Cool! I'm going to transform my comment into a proper answer so it can help other users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
let imageCropVC = RSKImageCropViewController()
```

you're initializing a controller with the `init` method.

So you can't use the `initWithImage()` method on this `imageCropVC` instance, because it would mean to initialize it again.

What you want is to initialize a new controller with an image:

```
let imageCropVC = RSKImageCropViewController(image: yourImage)
```